# How can I put a MatDialog in the foreground when I drag/click it? / Angular material

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I need to create several matdialog and they work like a Windows system. I want that when you drag/click a matdialog this comes to the foreground.

Right now my code is similar to this one (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-78ofcc-qsfafc), when I open several matdialog the last one appears in the foreground and I can't put another previous matdialog in the foreground.

I hope the dragged/clicked matdialog appears in the foreground

Comment: It doesnt matter that when you click on it the position stays the same?

Comment: @mtorreblanca no matter, I tried to change the position when I clicked, but the last matdialog continues in the foreground

Comment: great!, I think I know the solution